# How To Encrypt Connection String in Web.config - Retired Content?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, deprecated, aspnet-regiis.exe

I currently have an ASP.NET website that has an encrypted connection string within it's web.config file.  The settings are in the general AppSettings section, not the ConnectionString section.  Within the application code we manually decrypt the connection string at run time as needed.

While working on refactoring the site, I came across a method that Microsoft once suggested which involves running an `aspnet_regiis` command in order to insert encrypted data directly into the ConnectionString section of the web.config file.  This suggested method is now considered Retired Content although it doesn't say why (other than a small reference that some of the links may no longer be valid).

Here's the site I'm referring to:
[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx)

My questions are basically - Should I bother refactoring the existing functionality to use Microsoft's once recommended way?  I believe it would be more efficient than the current process.  Also, why would this method be considered Retired Content?  Is there a better way to do this, rather than my site supporting the encrypt/decrypt methods?

I've search Google & StackOverflow for other ways of doing this, but they all seem refer to Microsoft's way - or the way I currently have it implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the site/doc you're referring to is marked as obsolete, but the technology behind is not. Here are the official links, not marked as obsolete:

- [DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dpapiprotectedconfigurationprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (with an example), there is also the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider that is capable of encrypting sections
- [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)
- [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) with the -pe option

I would definitely use this technology.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that they say the documentation is considered retired content because it was written for the .NET 2.0 framework.  That being said, as Simon said, the technology behind it is still good to use.

The nice thing about using `aspnet_regiis` to encrypt your web.config file is that it is transparent to the application.  You can write your logic assuming that the appSettings or connectionStrings sections are not encrypted, and if they are are encrypted using this method the .NET framework will take care of decrypting them before giving you the value.

One thing to keep in mind with using this method is that it will encrypt the entire appSettings section.  If you open your web.config once it's encrypted you will not see any of the keys, but just a big encrypted hunk of data.

Comment: I ended up creating a separate section called 'secureAppSettings' and only encrypted that part - thus leaving the normal appSettings section unencrypted.